# Website stuck caching old files

Tags: html, web

I am working on a website, but whenever I upload a new file to my hosting provider (BlueHost), I cannot get the new version of the file to load in any browser or any PC that I have.  This happens with both images and html files.  I have tried loading the updated page on multiple computers on my network, but they all show the old version of the files.  The new files will load on my phone, but only on 3g.  I tried connecting through an Open VPN connection and this did not fix the issue, I also have cleared the cache in chrome on the computer.  Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: If your upload is successful then ther's nothing you have to do, just refresh page twice and it should be ready.

Comment: @armand No matter how much I refresh I get nothing new, unless I move off of my internal network onto the cellular network.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file. It might have server caching set up.

Comment: I am not using .htaccess.